# How can I run this VBS script from a shared network drive, from command line on multiple computers with different drive letter assignments?

Tags: vba, vbscript

What is the best way to run this VBS script which has its location on a shared network drive, i want it to run using command line, it will be used by multiple computers and each computer will have different drive letter assignments?

```
path = "C:\Users\ecaldwell"
filename = "PANESTCS.csv"
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path & filename, ForReading)
Set objResult = objFSO.CreateTextFile(path & filename & ".result.csv", True)    

i = 0  

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True

  data = objTextFile.Readline

  If inStr(data, ",") Then

row = split(data, ",")

If Ubound(row) > 8 Then

  ' If Column A = ‘D’  and Column E = Zero Then

  ' Move ‘5’ to Column I

  If row(0) = "D" And row(4) = "0" Then

    row(8) = "5"

  End If

End If 

Else

objTextFile.Skipline

 End If

  objResult.WriteLine Join(row, ",")

  i = i + 1

Loop

objTextFile.Close
objResult.Close 

Wscript.Echo "Processed " & i & " lines. " & path & filename & ".result.csv"
```

Comment: What is the problem? You can run the script from whatever drive the share is connected as, or you can run it directly via UNC path (`\\server\share\your.vbs`), provided it's a trusted location.

Comment: On a side note, how are other computers going to read from _your_ `C:\Users\ecaldwell` folder? :)

Comment: im obviously going to change it from that path when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Load    "i want it to run using command line"

Cscript.exe might be what you are looking for, it will run using cmd prompt [Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
"it will be used by multiple computers and each computer will have different drive letter assignments"
```

You can create a text file to read each computer name, and drive letter from, then iterate through it to pull out the computer name, drive letter and assign to variables which you will use to connect to the machine

**EDIT** - Adding information on reading csv file

```
Text file to load information from

Computer name, Drive letter
COMPUTER1,C
COMPUTER2,J
'Add other information
```

Load file as you have done in your code. To read csv file and load into variables you need to split on each "," mark

```
arrayMasterVariableFile = split(strLine, ",")

pcHostname = arrayMasterVariableFile(0)
pcDrive Letter = arrayMasterVariableFile(1)
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of the text file please?